Centering text with background color
Im currently trying to build a banner with the tagline( 30 years of discovery) to be centered under the title text with a light grey background only around the text. I'm able to have the text centered with a grey background spanning my entire screen. I am also able to have a colored background on just the text as long but without the text being centered on my screen.


.tagline {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-flexbox;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(100, 89, 95, 0.75);
}
<div class="tagline">
  <p> 30 Years of Discovery</p>
</div>



I would appreciate any insight that could be offered!
I've tried placing <p> in a span, which is where I was able to just have a background color on text. This didn't allow for me to center the div.

.tagline {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-flexbox;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  background-color: rgba(100, 89, 95, 0.75);
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You should use display: inline-block otherwise if it is considered block it is 100% width by default.


.tagline {
  text-align: center;
}

.tagline p {
  background-color: rgba(100, 89, 95, 0.75);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="tagline">
  <p> 30 Years of Discovery</p>
</div>




I don't know if this is what you want but something like this?
Css:
.tagline {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tagline__text {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 89, 95, 0.75);
}

Html:
<div class="tagline">
  <p  class="tagline__text"> 30 Years of Discovery</p>
</div>

